# Upsert in databricks using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, upsert

I am trying to create a df and store it as a delta table and trying to perform an upsert. I found this function online but just modified it to suit the path that I am trying to use.

```
delta_store='s3://raw_data/ETL_test/Delta/'
```

The df I create

```
Employee = Row("id", "FirstName", "LastName", "Email")
employee1 = Employee('1', 'Basher', 'armbrust', 'bash@gmail.com')
employee2 = Employee('2', 'Daniel', 'meng', 'daniel@stanford.edu')
employee3 = Employee('3', 'Muriel', None, 'muriel@waterloo.edu')
employee4 = Employee('4', 'Rachel', 'wendell', 'rach_3@imaginea.com')
employee5 = Employee('5', 'Zach', 'galifianakis', 'zach_g@pramati.co')
employee6 = Employee('6', 'Ramesh', 'Babu', 'ramesh@pramati.co')
employee7 = Employee('7', 'Bipul', 'Kumar', 'bipul@pramati.co')
employee8 = Employee('8', 'Sampath', 'Kumar', 'sam@pramati.co')
employee9 = Employee('9', 'Anil', 'Reddy', 'anil@pramati.co')
employee10 = Employee('10', 'Mageswaran', 'Dhandapani', 'mageswaran@pramati.co')

compacted_df = spark.createDataFrame([employee1, employee2, employee3, employee4, employee5, employee6, employee7, employee8, employee9, employee10])

display(compacted_df)
```

The upsert function:

```
def upsert(df, path=DELTA_STORE, is_delete=False):
  """
  Stores the Dataframe as Delta table if the path is empty or tries to merge the data if found
  df : Dataframe 
  path : Delta table store path
  is_delete: Delete the path directory
  """
  if is_delete:
    dbutils.fs.rm(path, True)
  if os.path.exists(path):
    print("Modifying existing table...")
    delta_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark,delta_store)
    match_expr = "delta.{} = updates.{}".format("id", "id")  and "delta.{} = updates.{}".format("FirstName", "FirstName")
    delta_table.alias("delta").merge(
              df.alias("updates"), match_expr) \
              .whenMatchedUpdateAll() \
              .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
              .execute()

  else:
    print("Creating new Delta table")
    df.write.format("delta").save(delta_store)
```

I then run the following code to modify the data and run into an error as follows:

```
employee14 = Employee('2', 'Daniel', 'Dang', 'ddang@stanford.edu')
employee15 = Employee('15', 'Anitha', 'Ramasamy', 'anitha@pramati.co')
ingestion_updates_df =  spark.createDataFrame([employee14, employee15])
upsert(df=ingestion_updates_df, is_delete=False)
```

Error:

```
AnalysisException: s3://raw_data/ETL_test/Delta already exists.
```

Can somebody explain what wrong am i doing here?

Answer (score 0):

This might be just a python - S3 logic error.

This `os.path.exists(path)` probably always returns false because it only understands posix filesystems and not S3 blob store paths.

On the second pass into your function, your code will go down the `ELSE` branch and end up trying to save (again) to the same path without using a `.mode("OVERWRITE")` option.